# Density of baryons

Tags: cosmology, density, estimation, baryons

I wanted to recalculate the number of atoms in the universe according to [What paper can I cite for the estimated number of atoms in the observable universe to be lower than $10^{82}$?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/322880/what-paper-can-i-cite-for-the-estimated-number-of-atoms-in-the-observable-univer) .

But in the cited paper
[Planck 2015 Results XIII Cosmological Parameters.pdf](http://planck.caltech.edu/pub/2015results/Planck_2015_Results_XIII_Cosmological_Parameters.pdf)
  the density of baryons (where it is about $0.025$, page $47$) differs from the one in the calculation above (where it is about $0.048$).
Why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number "~0.025" is not the baryon density parameter $\Omega_\mathrm{b}$, but $\omega_\mathrm{b} \equiv \Omega_\mathrm{b}h^2$, i.e. scaled by the dimensionless Hubble parameter $h \equiv H_0 \, / \,(100\,\mathrm{km}\,\mathrm{s}^{-1}\,\mathrm{Mpc}^{-1})$.

Using the "TT+lowP+lensing" numbers (which is common; you'll find them in 2nd column of Tab. 4, p. 31, in [Planck Collaboration et al. 2016](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.01589)),
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
h                      & = & 0.6781\pm0.0092,\\
\Omega_\mathrm{b}\,h^2 & = & 0.02226\pm0.00023,
\end{array}
$$
so
$$
\Omega_\mathrm{b} = 0.0484\pm0.0014,
$$
where I've simply assumed standard error propagation with no covariance.

Comment: Ah, ok. I saw the equation with the additional parameter but I thought this is the planck constant :D Thank you for the further information about the numbers!